# How to read_excel with a dayfirst condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read_excel through pandas. I have a date column in the format DD/MM/YYYY. Pandas will automatically read this as month first and as far as I've been able to tell there is no dayfirst function like there is with read_csv.
Is there a way to do read_excel while specifying date format?

```
xlxs_data = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx')
xlsx_data = xlxs_data.append(df, ignore_index=True, dayfirst=True)

TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dayfirst'
```

Comment: Could you try passing `dayfirst=True` `read_excel` accepts kwargs so it may work

Comment: I've added the code to the append. Dayfirst doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I mean to `read_excel` so `df = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx', dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Also why are you creating an empty df and then reading an excel sheet which will create a new df and appending it to the empty one?

Comment: fair point. It's code I've taken from elsewhere; you're right, I don't need to create an empty df and the append the new df to it. dayfirst did work, I was applying it to the wrong place. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `dayfirst=True` as a param to `read_excel`, although the docs don't state this is a param it recognises, it accepts kwargs and will resolve your problem:

```
df = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx', dayfirst=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately in Version 1.1.0 this is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

The `dayfirst` perimeter does not work with `read_excel` in Version 1.1.4 of pandas. The docs state "For non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after pd.read_excel."

So read in your data

```
df = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
```

Then use this

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col_name'], dayfirst=True)
```

Or this

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col_name'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Some info on format codes can be found here https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Remember that Pandas displays dates in ISO format YYYY-MM-DD. If you want to convert to a different format you need to convert the datetime object into a string. But if you do that you will lose all the functionality of datetime object so best to do that during export.

**UPDATE FOR PANDAS 2**

This answer is still true with Pandas 2.0.3

But since Pandas 2.0 `pd.read_excel` now has a `date_format` parameter which might work. But the docs do say "For anything more complex, please read in as object and then apply `to_datetime()` as-needed." So there might be some limitation when using `date_format`.